# Change which commit I made a branch from

Tags: git

I created a feature branch from the staging branch:

```
                                G --- H --- I
                               /            ^ feature, HEAD
A --- B --- C --- D --- E --- F
      ^ origin/staging        ^ staging
```

Commits `C` through `I` are unpushed.

I later realised that commits `C` through `F` are not relevant to my feature (perhaps they're untested). Let's assume `C` through `F` don't contain any changes that would affect the feature. I'd like to move that branch backwards, as if I created it at `B`:

```
        G --- H --- I
       /            ^ feature, HEAD
A --- B --- C --- D --- E --- F
      ^ origin/staging        ^ staging
```

How can I do this?

Comment: That operation is called "rebasing". *Usually* you rebase onto a newer commit, but technically nothing stops you from rebasing onto an older one.

Comment: From `feature`, `git rebase B` results in `Current branch feature is up to date.`

Comment: @snazzybouche that’s because it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called *rebasing* and has the command [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase). With this you can just

```sh
# on branch feature
git rebase staging --onto origin/staging
```

This will take all commits in `feature` made after the fork from `staging` - i.e. `G`, `H` and `I` - and *rebase* them [`--onto`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---ontoltnewbasegt) `origin/staging`, effectively removing all commits between `origin/staging` and `staging` from the `feature` branch - i.e. `C` to `F`.

Another option in this case would be to do an [`--interactive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---interactive) rebase and remove the unwanted commits in [*Interactive Mode*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode):

```sh
# on branch feature
git rebase -i origin/staging
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `git cherry-pick` G,H,I commits with a new branch starting at B.